# str.extract() with regex

Tags: regex, pandas

I need to split a column into two using regex and `str.extract()` (assuming this is best)

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
                        'Product': ['Truly Mix 2/12Pk Cans - 12Z',
                                    'Bud 16Z - LOOSE -  16Z',
                                    'Blue Moon (Case 12x - 22Z)',
                                    '2 for the show (6/4PK - 16Z)']
             })
```

I would like this result:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
                          'Product': ['Truly Mix', 'Bud', 'Blue Moon', '2 for the show'],
                          'Packaging': ['2/12Pk Cans - 12Z',
                                        '16Z - LOOSE -  16Z',
                                        'Case 12x - 22Z',
                                        '6/4PK - 16Z' ]
                 })
```

I tried a lot of things, but still struggle with regex, even after lots of online learning.

Here is my final attempt at getting the product:

```
pattern = r'(\D+)[^\w][^(Case][^0-9]'

df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.extract(pattern)
```

`str.replace()` should work fine for getting rid of the parenthesis, just can't get that far.

I'm just not even close after 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the two parts of each entry into two columns, and then remove `(` and `)` at the start/end of the string where they are present:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['Truly Mix 2/12Pk Cans - 12Z','Bud 16Z - LOOSE -  16Z','Blue Moon (Case 12x - 22Z)','2 for the show (6/4PK - 16Z)']})
pattern = r'^(.*?)\s*((?:\((?:Case\b)?|\d+(?:/\d+)?[A-Za-z]+\b).*)'
df[['Product', 'Packaging']] = df['Product'].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
df['Packaging'] = df['Packaging'].str.replace(r'^\((.*)\)$', r'\1', regex=True)
# => >>> print(df['Packaging'])
#    0     2/12Pk Cans - 12Z
#    1    16Z - LOOSE -  16Z
#    2        Case 12x - 22Z
#    3           6/4PK - 16Z
# => >>> print(df['Product'])
#    0         Truly Mix
#    1               Bud
#    2         Blue Moon
#    3    2 for the show
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/14ER3s/1). *Regex details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  -`\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:\((?:Case\b)?|\d+(?:/\d+)?[A-Za-z]+\b).*)` - Group 2:

  - `(?:\((?:Case\b)?|\d+(?:/\d+)?[A-Za-z]+\b)` - either of

    - `\((?:Case\b)?` - a `(` and then an optional whole word `Case`
    - `|` - or
    - `\d+(?:/\d+)?[A-Za-z]+\b` - one or more digits, an optional sequence of `/` and one or more digits, and one or more letters (followed with a word boundary)
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

The `.replace(r'^\((.*)\)$', r'\1', regex=True)` part remove `(` and `)` at the start and end of the string where they are both present.